# Looking for Euler square solver

Tags: logical-deduction

> I'm looking for a solver of a Greco-Latin square (Euler square) that can calculate all combinations given some hints.
>
> Maybe you can help me.
> Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What exactly are you looking for - an answer for a particular puzzle, a strategy for solving a type of puzzle, an algorithm that can solve different puzzles...?

Comment: I'm looking for an app where I can configurate the grid (number of cases) and the hints. And it wil return the solution(s).

Comment: I found one but it's not free. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am envisioning an Euler square as a grid of ordered pairs, where the first coordinates and the second coordinates form Latin squares with the same symbol sets, {1, 2,..., n}, and each order pair appears exactly once.

Here's an example of a partially clued 3 x 3 Euler square:

```
(1,2)  ( , )  ( , )
( , )  ( , )  (3, )
( , )  ( ,2)  ( , )
```

To solve this, copy paste the following code into the text field at

http://potassco.sourceforge.net/clingo.html,

and after reasoning mode, select "enumerate all." It will output two possible solutions.

The language is Clingo, which is for answer set programming. The solutions are outputted in a rather unreadable format, unfortunately. I do not have enough knowledge of the language to make improve this.

```
symbol(1..3). % Replace 3 with n for an n x n grid.

% Replace everything from here...
paint1(1,1,1). 
paint2(1,1,2).
paint2(3,2,2).
paint1(2,3,3).
%...to here with the clues for your puzzle.

%paint1(R,C,P) means that the first coordinate of the square at
%row R and column C is labeled P.
%paint2(R,C,P) means that the second coordinate of the square at
%row R and column C is labeled P.

%A square is a pair of symbols.
square(R, C) :- symbol(R), symbol(C).

%Each square is painted with at most one color, in both squares.
1 { paint1(R, C, P) : symbol(P) } 1 :- square(R, C).
1 { paint2(R, C, P) : symbol(P) } 1 :- square(R, C).

%No repeats in a row, in either square
:- paint1(R, C1, P), paint1(R, C2, P), C1 != C2.
:- paint2(R, C1, P), paint2(R, C2, P), C1 != C2.
%No repeats in a column, in either square
:- paint1(R1, C, P), paint1(R2, C, P), R1 != R2.
:- paint2(R1, C, P), paint2(R2, C, P), R1 != R2.
%No two squares in different rows can be colored the same in both squares.
:- paint1(R1, C1, P1), paint2(R1, C1, P2), paint1(R2, C2, P1), paint2(R2, C2, P2), R1 != R2.
%No two squares in different columns can be colored the same in both squares.
:- paint1(R1, C1, P1), paint2(R1, C1, P2), paint1(R2, C2, P1), paint2(R2, C2, P2), C1 != C2.

#show paint1/3.
#show paint2/3.
```

This is adapted from a sudoku solver I found at at https://github.com/joelverhagen/Sudoku-Solver-in-Clasp-Gringo/blob/master/sudoku.lp

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try to adapt for a 7x7 grid.

Comment: I tried the program. The program crached with error message.Maybe a 7x7 grid is too hard for this online solver ? " clingo version 5.0.0
Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with  -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X  with X higher than the current value "  etc....

Comment: Try changing the reasoning mode from “enumerate all” to “cautious”, and after that, maybe “default”. This should get you several valid solutions, if not all of them. You’re right though, I think the search space is to big for this program, which is basically brute force.

Comment: That works ! But.... the given solution is false ! The program is missing that there can't have the same combination in the grid...Not 2 (4,3) for example ...

Comment: Once again :thank you for your help ! there it is : paint1(1,2,1). 
paint2(1,3,1).
paint2(1,4,2).
paint2(2,5,3).
paint1(2,6,2).
paint1(2,7,3).
paint2(3,7,1).
paint2(4,2,4).
paint2(4,3,5).
paint2(4,4,3).
paint1(4,6,3).
paint2(5,1,4).
paint1(5,3,4).
paint2(5,3,6).
paint1(5,6,5).
paint1(6,2,6).
paint2(6,2,2).
paint2(6,3,4).
paint1(7,2,3).
paint1(7,5,1).
paint2(7,6,5).

Comment: I fixed it! It now outputs the following solution for your 7x7 puzzle https://pastebin.com/raw/F9XpEWqV And it worked with enumerate all, proving this solution is unique

Comment: Did you change the code ? I see no differences. I don't understand your solution.... First line should be like this (xx) (1x)(x1)(x2)(xx)(xx)(xx) How can we talk ? chatting is forbidden as I am understanding

Comment: Whoops, I interchanged row with column on accident, here is the correct solution https://pastebin.com/raw/BrN8XVym Click on the link that says "edited x hours ago" at the bottom of the post to see the changes

Comment: You're an hero ! It's perfect ! Thank you for your time and your help ! Merci beaucoup !